# MKOverlayPathRenderer invert fill area

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have a polygonal area described in an MKOverlayPathRenderer. Instead of filling in the area enclosed in the polygon, I instead want to fill in the area that lies outside of it.

How could I invert the fill area of the MKOverlayPathRenderer?

This is the function where the renderer is fetched:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = parser.rendererForOverlay(overlay)! as! MKOverlayPathRenderer
    renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    return renderer
}
```

Comment: The reminders app does something similar. If you zoom out quickly you can confuse it and see that it just renders a massive square with a hole cut out of it. With a renderer subclass you could do the same effect.

Comment: @KaneCheshire, do you know what would be involved in achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "interiorPolygons" when you draw your overlay :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D polygoneCoords[10]
= { {Point1LAT,Point1LONG}, {Point2LAT,Point2LONG}, {Point3LAT,Point3LONG}, {Point4LAT,Point4LONG},{Point5LAT,Point5LONG},{Point6LAT,Point6LONG},{Point7LAT,Point7LONG},{Point8LAT,Point8LONG},{Point9LAT,Point9LONG},{Point10LAT,Point10LONG}};
self.myPolygoneArea = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:polygoneCoords count:10];

CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCoords[6] = { {90, 0}, {90, 180}, {-90,180}, {-90,0}, {-90,-180}, {90,-180} };
myOverlay = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:worldCoords count:6 interiorPolygons:[NSArray arrayWithObject:myPolygoneArea]];

[self.MyMap addOverlay:myOverlay];

-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

MKPolygonRenderer *polygon = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc]initWithOverlay:overlay];

polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
polygon.lineWidth = 2;
polygon.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];

return polygon;}
```

Hope this help ...